# Apps Script projects disappeared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail-api, drive

I created a few Apps Script projects and 2 of them disappeared and don't show up on my projects folder... I didn't change the code or anything. I crated the projects and everything worked fine for a few weeks, then a few days ago I started receiving emails that those 2 scripts were not firing. When I went looking for the cause I saw that the projects were gone... Now I lost the code...
Is there a way to recover the code/projects?

I've searched in the trash and projects folders.

Thanks you in advance.
André.

Comment: Speak with google support